# i want to load images from NSData but scrolling not smoothly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am storing images as *base64* `NSData` in database and getting from Database and display in `UICollectionView` `cellForItemAtIndexPath`as `cell.bgImageView.image`images are displaying but scrolling is not smooth and when i am trying to get back from another `ViewController` its taking too much time to load the view.

**CODE**

`NSData *imageData=[[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:itemObj.strImage options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];`

```
cell.bgImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

**Code**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ItemViewController *vc = [[ItemViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ItemViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
Item *itemObject = [[Item alloc]init];
itemObject = [arrayOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
vc.strItemName = itemObject.strItemName;
vc.strItemDesc = itemObject.strShortDescription;
vc.strImage = itemObject.strImage;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

above is the code for next viewController and passing values and iam come back to CollectionView like this

```
- (void)dismiss{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: show your code so we can further understand the requirement and how to solve it

Comment: dude put it on the question not on the comments to better readability

Comment: Why don't you store image url in database instead of base64 and use lazyloading of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Write image in doc directory and store that path in db.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting image as below,

```
[UIImage imageWithData:data]
```

this is synchronous operation, so it will block your main thread until it finishes loading.
THis is the reason why your scroll view is jerky because you blocked the main thread.
Try loading the images in backGround Thread, it will definitely solve ur problem.

Code for loading in backGround thread,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"www.example.com"]];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           cell.myImageView.image = image;
        });
});
```

Comment: but i don't know how to load with asynchronous operation..iam new to objective c please post a code

Comment: updated the code.Since it loads in background thread and you are reusing tableViewCells, sometimes image will be applies to wrong cell.So make sure it applies to correct cell.

Comment: i have tried with your code but still same issue. when i click on collectionview cell controller goes to next View and come back to CollectionView its taking too much time

Comment: is your app appears like its UI is blocked or the animation is taking too long time?

Comment: when press Cancel Button View get back to UICollectionView At this time it is taking time

Comment: is your scrollView fixed? or is it still lagging?. post some code on how you are getting back to collectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Put your iimage loading code in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        your code here....
  });
```